# Loading JSON Array Into BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a json array into a bigquery table. The structure of the data is as stated below :

```
[{"image":"testimage1","component":"component1"},{"image":"testimage2","component":"component2"}]
```

Each json record corresponds to 1 row in BigQuery. The columns in BigQuery are : image and component.
When I am trying to ingest the data it fails with a parsing error.
If I try to change the structure to this , it works

```
 {"image":"testimage1","component":"component1"}{"image":"testimage2","component":"component2"}
```

I am trying to ingest as `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`
Is there any way I can make the first json structure get ingested into Bigquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only a valid JSON can be ingested by BigQuery and a valid JSON doesn't start by an array.

You have to transform it slightly:

- Either transform it in a valid JSON (add a `{"object":` at the beginning and finish the line by a `}`). Ingest that JSON in a temporary table and perform a query to scan the new table and insert the correct values in the target tables
- Or remove the array definition `[]` and replace the `},{` by `}\n{` to have a JSON line.

Alternatively, you can ingest your JSON as a CSV file (you will have only 1 column with you JSON raw text in it) and then use the BigQuery String function to transform the data and insert them in the target database.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this approach of looping through the list and writing it into a json file; then load the json file into BigQuery.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import json

client = bigquery.Client(project="project-id")

dataset_id = "dataset-id"
table_id = "bqjson"


list_dict =[{"image":"testimage1","component":"component1"},{"image":"testimage2","component":"component2"}]


with open ("sample-json-data.json", "w") as jsonwrite:
   for item in list_dict:
       jsonwrite.write(json.dumps(item) + '\n')     #newline delimited json file


dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)


job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
job_config.autodetect = True

with open("sample-json-data.json", "rb") as source_file:
   job = client.load_table_from_file(
       source_file,
       table_ref,
       location="us",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
       job_config=job_config,
   )  # API request

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

Output:

[image]